# jhipster filter results are returned correclty but when I click the UI to navigate to page 2 in the result set I get the unfiltered results back again

Tags: angular, pagination, jhipster

I used the generator to create the entities and filtering (with service class) via the JDL import. All good. It took some time but I figured out how to get the filter working using a form field entry in the UI

```
<form [formGroup]="filterForm" (ngSubmit)="onEnter()">
   <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
</form>
```

and added the required method in the component.ts class

```
 onEnter(): void {
      if (this.filterForm.get('ticker').value) {
          this.signalServiceService
          .query({ 'ticker.contains': this.filterForm.get('ticker').value })
          .subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<ISignalService[]>) => this.onSuccess(res.body, res.headers, 1, true),
            () => this.onError()
          );;
      }
  }
```

this works great for entering my value to filter in the field I created then hitting the enter key and results are returned to the UI correctly.

The problem I face is that when I click on the UI navigate buttons to move to page 2 in the results set the loadPage function is called which overwrites my filtered results with the entire result set and that means I land on page 2 but with the entire unfiltered result set.

So the question is how do I maintain the filtered result set across page clicks in the UI?

Thanks in advance for any help or tips anyone can provide to point me in the right direction.

I should add this is a jhipster monolith with mysql H2 using generator-jhipster@6.10.3

Comment: First step is to determine whether your request is built correctly or if the issue comes from response processing.
 Are you calling `createRequestOption` in `signalServiceService.query()` to add pagination HttpParams? Do you get a correct `Pageable` in server under debugger and is it used in your query service?

Comment: Can you give more info about `loadPage`? is that a method in the component? If you can provide snippets of what is triggered when "page 2" is clicked (is it a router outlet or a method?), that would be helpful

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. @GaëlMarziou - you were right, I found that my implementation had two issues 1) my function onEnter was unnecessary and I needed to modify the jhipster created loadPage function and 2) based on this new loadPage function the HttpParams request had to be correctly formed in request-utils. I'll post my full answer

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://gitlab.com/ImperfectClone/jhipster-filter-criteria-test

which helped me to implement the following:

1. a form in the UI

```
<form name="searchForm" class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
       [(ngModel)]="criteria.ticker" id="tickerSerchText" name="tickerSerchText" >
            <button class="input-group-addon btn btn-info" (click)="loadPage()">
                 <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
            </button>
</form>
```

2. modify the constructor of the component with a placeholder for the search value

```
constructor(
    protected signalServiceService: SignalServiceService,
    protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    protected dataUtils: JhiDataUtils,
    protected router: Router,
    protected eventManager: JhiEventManager,
    protected modalService: NgbModal
  ) {
        this.criteria = {
          ticker: null 
        }
  }
```

3. modify the jHipster created loadPage method to add the search value into the request when a value is entered in the UI field

```
loadPage(page?: number, dontNavigate?: boolean): void {
    
    const pageToLoad: number = page || this.page || 1;

    const criteria = [];

    if (this.criteria.ticker != null && this.criteria.ticker !== '') {
      criteria.push({key: 'ticker.contains', value: this.criteria.ticker});
    }
    
    this.signalServiceService
      .query({ 
        page: pageToLoad - 1,
        size: this.itemsPerPage,
        sort: this.sort(),
        criteria
      })
      .subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<ISignalService[]>) => this.onSuccess(res.body, res.headers, pageToLoad, !dontNavigate), 
        () => this.onError()
      );
  }
```

4. modify the jHipster created createRequestOption in request-utils.ts to set the criteria into the request object when they are present

```
  if (req) {
    Object.keys(req).forEach(key => {
      if (key !== 'sort') {
        if (key !== 'criteria') {
          options = options.set(key, req[key]);
        } else {
          req.criteria.forEach((criterion: { key: string; value: string; }) => {
            options = options.set(criterion.key, criterion.value);
          });
        }
      }
    });

    if (req.sort) {
      req.sort.forEach((val: string) => {
        options = options.append('sort', val);
      });
    }
  }
```

5. build and run